# How to DataBind DataContext for printing

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have 2 XAML pages :

a)  PagePrinting.xaml
 b)  FormattedPage.xaml

```
--1--- in FormattedPage.xaml , I have a RichtextBlock :

<RichTextBlock>
 <Paragraph>
 <InlineUIContainer>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> 
          <!-- Data Template -->
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
 </ItemsControl>
</InlineUIContainer>
</Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>


------2--  In PagePrinting.xaml :

I have the data from SQLite Db for FormattedPage.XAML for above (1)


ObservableCollection <Transaction> TransCollection = new ObservableCollection <Transaction>();

OnPageLoad :

TransCollection.Clear();

var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
var Trans = await db.QueryAsync <BizTransaction>("Select * From BizTransaction Where SalesId = '" + Id + "'");         

int intRecord = Trans.Count();

if (intRecord != 0)
 {
   foreach (var _trans in Trans)
   {
      int Id = _trans.Id;
      string Name = _trans.Description;
      string ItemNo = _trans.No;
      int Qty = (int)_trans.Quantity;
      decimal Price = _trans.UnitPrice;
      decimal LineAmt = _trans.LineAmount;

      //-- create a collection
     AddToList(Id, Name, ItemNo, Qty, Price, LineAmt);

   }


this.DataContext = TransCollection;

 FrameworkElement page1;

 page1 = new FormattedPage();

 page1.DataContext = this.DataContext;

 CanvasPrintContainer.Children.Add(page1);



The problems:

1) is this correct ? 

this.DataContext = TransCollection;
page1.DataContext = this.DataContext;

2) How to do Binding in FormattedPage.xaml using this DataContext?

3) What need to be done in xaml section for PagePrinting for DataBinding ?


Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently the best example.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6